# find the sequence $A$ so that $A < B$ for all $B$ in $S_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, induction, contest-math

> Let $S_n$ be the set of all strictly decreasing sequences of $n$ positive integers so that no term divides any other term. Given two sequences $A = (a_i)$ and $B = (b_j)$, we say $A < B$ if for some $k, a_k < b_k, a_i = b_i\,\forall i < k.$ Find the sequence $A$ in $S_n$ so that $A<B$ for any other $B$ in $S_n$.

I found the solution below online, but I was wondering how to justify why it works? I'm not sure how to show that for all other such sequences $B$ in $S_n,  A_n < B$. The method seems intuitive and I think it's useful to note that since all odd terms must be distinct, the maximum term in $S$ must be at least $2 n - 1,$ the minimum possible odd term. Then basically the solution "goes down" as far as possible before taking terms from $A_k$. One might need to check the case for small n. Clearly, $A_1, A_2, A_3$ are all minimum.

Also, as for the proof as to why no term in $A_n$ divides another, I think it's because the maximum exponent of $2$ dividing each term in $A_n$ is either 1, or $k$ or $k+1$ for some nonnegative integer k. This could probably be proved by induction. It clearly holds for $n=1,2,3$.

Solution:

[image]